# Pygame python 3.1

Tags: python, pygame

I need help in pygame for 3.1 i am watching The New Bostons tutorials and whenever I put in

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
```

I receive

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Aidan\Desktop\pygame.py", line 8, in 
    import pygame
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Aidan\Desktop\pygame.py", line 9, in 
    from pygame.locals import *
```

ImportError: No module named locals

Comment: PS, can you provide a link to the tutorial? Considering that 2 people in 2 days ran into exactly this problem, it might be worth seeing if the tutorial is misleading and sending someone an email about it…

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that your script (or something else it imports) is already named `pygame`. So, Python can't find the package with the same name.

Just rename your script to something else, like `my_game.py`.

Comment: Thanks might work great reply speed,Worked i ha old python installe which bugged it THAnK YOU

Comment: @user2344757: Did you _rename_ it, or just create a new file, leaving the old one behind? As long as you still have any `pygame.py` (or, possibly, `pygame.pyc`) file sitting around in the working directory, you won't be able to access the `pygame` package.